# how to inject javascript function code along with html code?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
let hideText = () => {
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  console.log(selection.toString())
  
  if (selection.toString() === "") {
    console.log("Selection Error");
  } else {
    console.assert(selection.focusNode == selection.anchorNode);
    let selectionText = selection.toString();
    let selectionNode = selection.anchorNode.parentElement;
    selectionNode.innerHTML = selectionNode.innerHTML.replace(selectionText,
      `
      <textarea>${selectionText}</textarea>
      <button onclick="count(1)">+</button> 
      <button onclick="count(-1)">-</button>`
      );
  }
```

so above functions run when a user presses a dblctrl, but as shown in last two lines, i have count() to be run, which i have defined in the tool script. if  i inject this code into any webpage and press the button, then count function doesnt run, because it is defined in my script not on the webpage, so how can i push my count() along with this html code written in strings to the webpage.

````
function count(num, selectionNode){
  click+=num;
  fontsz = parseFloat((fontsz))+(num*0.5)+"em";
  document.querySelector("span").style.fontSize=fontsz;
}```

this is my count function.
````

Answer (score 0):

You can add scripts to a page.

```
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = "https://example.com" // load your script
// or script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oldButton.innerHTML))
document.body.appendChild(script)
```

Just mentioning that injecting javascript into other people's sites is unethical and in some cases criminal, you should only be doing this if you own those sites or have permission to do so.

Comment: // script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oldButton.innerHTML))|

how do i put in my function count in here? i dont understand what "oldButton.innerHTML" is  here?